# I need a Antivirus Scanner for SharePoint 2013

Tags: security, anti-virus

I'm using a Windows 2012 server. With SharePoint server 2013 installed.

When I wanted to install Forefront for SharePoint 2010 I get this error.

No protectable server applications were detected. Client-only installation is not currently supported.
For examples of server applications see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=147673 or http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=147674. Note that some roles for these applications may not be protectable.

I think this is because forefront for SharePoint 2010 is not supported. Is there a alternative program for SharePoint server 2013 that I can install?

Answer (score 2):

None of the major SharePoint Anti-Virus vendors have released a version compatible with 2013 yet.  I don't expect they will until closer to the GA release.

Answer (score 0):

Although still in beta stage, you might want to evaluate the product from ESET: http://www.eset.com/beta/sharepoint/. It covers SharePoint versions from 2007 to 2013.